# Lunching atl files using ATL plugin

Tags: uml

I am using ATl plugin to lunch atl using java class.
Before i was running ATL files by using ATL configuration wizard.
The input i was giving in the configuration were:

- **ATL Module:** sample.atl
- **Metamodel UML:** sampleprofile.uml
- **Source Model system:** samplemodel.uml
- **Target:** output.uml

After running the output was the correct and the one i wanted.

The problem is that when i use the ATL plugin to lunch the atl files it only requires me as input:
Name of the ATL file and Name of the metamodel.The problem is that i dont know where to specify the samplemodel.uml. Because this should be also as input. Therefore the output.uml i am getting is not the one i am expecting to get.

Does anyone know how can i specify this second file inside the generated java class ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please retag, it has nothing to do with [`atl`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atl)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to change the generated java class. Just import the generated class (for instance `Families2Persons`) from your java program and launch the transformation like this:

```
Families2Persons runner = new Families2Persons();
runner.loadModels("/pathto/samplemodel.uml");
runner.doFamilies2Persons(new NullProgressMonitor());
runner.saveModels("/pathto/output.uml");
```

If you want you can also launch the transformation from command line passing the two paths as arguments.

Comment: The problem is that i have two files as input samplemodel.uml and sampleprofile.uml which are depended with each other. I can not run samplemodel.uml if i do not rung the sampleprofile.uml. I tried to put them both like :Families2Persons runner = new Families2Persons();
runner.loadModels("/pathto/sampleprofile.uml"); runner.loadModels("/pathto/samplemodel.uml");
runner.doFamilies2Persons(new NullProgressMonitor());
runner.saveModels("/pathto/output.uml");                                                      but it doesnt work . it gives me errors